# Posting files to a chat through Slack API

Tags: python, slack-api

I'm trying to deliver videos, through Slack API using Python's library `slackclient`.

I often use `slack.api_call('chat.postMessage'...)` and I am familiar with `'files.upload'` but when I execute

```
slack = SlackClient(TOKEN)
slack.api_call('files.upload', file=open('video.mp4', 'rb')...)
```

the file is uploaded to the given channel, but is not posted as a message.

What I am trying to achieve is to create a message which I can send as a private message or to a channel that would look something like this

[image]

and maybe add some text above it if possible.

I've explored the [Attachment](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments) section in the docs, but couldn't find anything related to files.
If there is a way to not supply the file in binary format, but as a link that would also be ok (as long as it is displayed in an embedded fashion).

Answer (score 6):

How about this sample script? It uses `io.BytesIO(f.read())` for the file. In order to use this, `files:write:user` has to be included in the scopes. About the text, you can import it using `initial_comment`. In my environment, `attachments` could not be used for `files.upload`. The API document is https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload.

#### Script :

```
with open('./sample.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    slack.api_call(
        "files.upload",
        channels='#sample',
        filename='sample.mp4',
        title='sampletitle',
        initial_comment='sampletext',
        file=io.BytesIO(f.read())
    )
```

#### Result :

[image]

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: I will try this code tomorrow, and see what happened. Maybe it's relevant that I am not using my own token, I'm uploading as a bot (using as_user). I tried making files.upload call before posting this and it resulted in uploading a file to the channel, but no message was shown (I could only see it on the side menu of the files, but not in the chat). Maybe one of the parameters you added to the call does the job, I'll report tomorrow

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work, results in the same result being the video is uploaded to the channel (I can see it on the file menu) but it is not displayed in the chat window

Comment: @bluesummers In my environment, this works fine. I used the channel I created and an access token retrieved from my account. Can I ask you about your environment? I couldn't know it from your question. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: I'm using legacy tokens, used exactly the code you posted and it doesn't show this kind of message in the chat - link to legacy tokens -> https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens

Comment: @bluesummers In my environment, using both access token obtained from OAuth2 and Legacy tokens, the movie can be uploaded to channel like above. And even if in the case of an user who is not owner of the channel can also upload the movie like above. Can I see your whole script? And can I ask you about your detail environment?

Comment: this is the entire code https://ibb.co/hwH5hF - the result is the file is uploaded to the channel files, but is not showing as a message

Comment: @bluesummers Can you import your whole code on your question? When I see your url, it becomes image data. I don't know the reason. I'm sorry.

Comment: @bluesummers Can you try as follows? For ``channels``, please modify to ``channels='#bla'`` and ``channels='### channel id ###'``.

Comment: @bluesummers Can I ask you about the response from Slack when you upload the file? And are you owner of the channel?

Answer (score 6):

I came across this question because I had the same issue - my file would upload and I would get a response, but the file would not be posted to the channel I had sent.  It turned out to be a poor job by me of reading the Slack API documentation. I had used `chat.postMessage` many times and included a single 'channel' argument.  Here is that API: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

The `files.upload` method it wants a comma separated list of channels in a 'channels' argument.  See https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload  Once I changed from 'channel' to 'channels' *and* made sure to pass it as a list, I was successfully posting the image to the channel I wanted.

To the original question then, in your link to the code you used (https://ibb.co/hwH5hF) try changing `channel='bla'`to `channels=['bla']`

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
import slack

client = slack.WebClient(token='xoxb-XXX')

with open('/path/to/attachment.jpeg', 'rb') as att:
    r = client.api_call("files.upload", files={
        'file': att,
    }, data={
        'channels': '#my_channel',
        'filename': 'downloaded_filename.jpeg',
        'title': 'Attachment\'s title',
        'initial_comment': 'Attachment\'s description',
    })
    assert r.status_code == 200
```